# How to build a macro that return the absolute value of an argument of another macro?

Tags: macros

How can I build a macro that return the absolute value of an argument of another macro? I would like that the `\abs` macro return the absolute value of the its argument.

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{<implementation>}
\newcommand{\command}[2]{\raisebox{\numexpr\abs{#1}*#1\relax\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{}{}}
```

So whether I use a positive or negative number as argument, the expression `\abs{#1}` will always be positive.

Comment: `\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\ifnum#1<0 -\fi#1}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--1` is legal in `\numexpr`, equivalent to `1`. So

```
\newcommand{\absval}[1]{\ifnum#1<0 -\fi#1}
```

is what you're looking for. Then

```
\newcommand{\command}[2]{%
  \raisebox{\numexpr\absval{#1}\relax\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{}{}}
```

will do.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\abs` instead of `\absval` in the first snippet to be compatible with the second one?

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, it should. ;-)